# Style messing up when screen size is reduced

Tags: html, css, media-queries, responsive

Please take a look at my practice site - http://codepen.io/silentarrowz/pen/rLJABR

I am having few problems with it:

1. At reduced screen size the eElectronics and cart at the top are not centered but appear at one side of the screen. I'd like it to be centered for small screen sizes. I am able to center the eElectronics logo but unable to center the cart div, even though I am using media queries.
2. The navigation bar overflows for small screen sizes and the links at the end such as OTHERS & CONTACT flow on to the next row. How do I  fix this?
3. The carousel caption moves off the screen for reduced size. How do I fix this?

Please offer your suggestions and advice.

```
.navcolor{
  background-color:#1abc9c;
}
.logo a{
  padding-bottom:10px;
  color:#999;
}
.logo a span{
  color:#1abc9c;
}
.cart {
  border:1px solid rgb(221,221,221);
  font-family:"Titillium Web";
  font-size:18px;
  width:140px;
  height:50px;
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-left:10px;
}
.cart a{
  color:#666;
}
.cart a span{
  color:#1abc9c;
  font-weight:bold;
}
.cart:hover {
  background-color : #1abc9c;
}
.cart:hover span, .cart:hover a{
  color:white;
}
.no-underline :hover{
  text-decoration:none;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-menu{
   height:50px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-menu li > a{
  color:white;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:14px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-menu > .active > a {
  background-color:#333;
  color:white;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-menu > .active > a:hover {
  background-color:#333;
  color:white;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-menu li>a:hover{
  background-color:#333;
  color:white;
}
#carousel1 img{
  width:100%;
  height:70%;
}
.logo{
  font-family:"Titillium Web";
  font-size:40px;
}
.cart{
  font-size:18px;   
}
.carouse-inner{
  position:relative;
}
.carousel-caption{
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color:white;
  display:block;
  width:600px;
  padding-left:20px;
  text-align:left;
  position:absolute;
  left:600px;
  bottom:150px;
}
.latest img{
  border:1px solid grey;
}
.details p{
  height:150px;
  display:block;
  border:1px solid #17a78b;
  margin-top:30px;
  margin-bottom:30px;
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight:200;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
}
.details p:hover{
  background-color:black;
}
.details p>i{
  font-size:50px;
  font-weight:500;
}
.details{
  background-color:rgb(26,188,156);
}
.latest{
  text-align:center;
}
@media (max-width: 300px) {
  .logo{
    text-align:center;
  }
  .cart{
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
  }   
}

@media (min-width: 501px) {
  .logo {
    float: left;
  }
  .cart {
    float:right;
  }
}
```

Comment: If we fixed your problem please vote for an answer or give us some feedback!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to center divs with text-align that's not the way to go. You need to set up margin on right and left to auto:

```
    @media (max-width: 300px) {
      .logo{
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
     }
     .cart{
        width:100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
     }
}
```

The thing is your eElectronics is not taking all the space of the div, center div with margin auto on sides and text-align center inside the div.

For the menu in collapse mode, i get a scroll bar and everything is fine except it is a little small. Override with overflow: visible; and set z-index if it overlaps under other items.

```
.navbar-collapse.in {
    overflow-y: visible;
}
```

The carousel captions are fine for me on Firefox. You just need to set a width in % and set margins on each side to auto. That div needs to be adaptative. Right now it stay at a size of 600px set in .carousel-caption.

Comment: I had to make a few changes to the code for it to work.
here's the code that worked - 
@media (max-width: 500px) {
      .logo{
        text-align:center;
     }
     .cart{
        width:100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
       text-align:center;
     }
}

So, question 1 is solved now.
Could you help with questions 2 & 3 ??

Comment: I get a scroll for the menu in collapse. And everything looks good, but its a bit small. Have you tried this on other browsers?

Comment: yeah, I am getting a scroll in the menu too, when collapsed. dont know why that's happening

Comment: I have edited my answer check it out, you need to override the overflow to visible. Overflow is on auto and that by default set scrolling on. If you want scrolls just set height to bigger than what you have or override the overflow to visible.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 2:** Your OTHER & CONTACT menu buttons go on the next row because your navbar is in a div.container with a width of 750px for resolutions under 768px, and there is no place for themin the same row.

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
    .container {
        width: 750px;
    }
}
```

You could give it another class, with different width, since you have the .container class assigned to more divs, and make it wider.

You could also give a min-height of 330px to your .navbar-colapse.in class to make the collapsed menu higher when resolution is under 768px:

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
    .navbar-collapse.in {
        overflow-y: auto;
        min-height: 330px;
    }
}
```

**Problem 3:** As Steve said, change your .carousel-caption style, giving width in percents (100%) and margins set to auto.

```
.carousel-caption {
    width: 100%;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
}
```